# sql server partitioned table related indexes

Tags: partitioning, sql-server-2017

I have a huge table which contains around 3B records.
this table contains 3 indexes :

- 1 clustered index on date and ID fields
- 1 non-clustered index on date
- 1 non-clustered index on ID

I want to transform this table into a partitioned table based on date field (each partition will have 4 hours)

the idea of partitioned table is clear , but I'm confused regarding the indexes.
can I keep the same indexes ? do I have to create partitioned indexes ?

All hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> can I keep the same indexes ?

Yes, you can. You can create indexes on partitioned table the same way. In fact every table is partitioned - non-partitioned tables are actually tables with a single partition.

> do I have to create partitioned indexes ?

No, you don't have to. But it is highly recommended to align your table and its indexes, otherwise you will lose the advantages of having partitioned table, like swapping partitions. When a table and its indexes are in alignment, SQL Server can switch partitions quickly and efficiently while maintaining the partition structure of both the table and its indexes.